# Soup of the day: best served during election season

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, stackexchange, beautifulsoup

Community moderator elections on the Stack Exchange network are really exciting.
Alas, on the [page of the primaries](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1), I find it mildly annoying that candidates are randomly reordered on every page load, even if it's surely for a good reason.

So, I cooked up (pun totally intended) this script using [Beautiful Soup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) in Python to list the candidates in an election by their score. To use it, install `beautifulsoup4` (for example with `pip install --user beautifulsoup4`), and then to list the candidates running for Code Review:

> ```
> $ python primaries.py so -n 6  # the 6th election on Stack Overflow
> 10905   Martijn Pieters
> 7310    meagar
> 5923    Jon Clements
> 5461    Matt
> 5211    Madara Uchiha
> 4133    deceze
> 3301    Raghav Sood
> 3180    Paresh Mayani
> 3126    Jeremy Banks
> 2651    Ed Cottrell
> ```

Since all the Stack Exchange sites seem to use the same format, it can work with all Stack Exchange sites. For the sake of a POC I included support for a few other sites (use "so" for Stack Overflow, "sf" for Server Fault), obviously it should be extended for others. Another feature I plan to add soon is to find the latest election by default, rather than using the first.

I mainly suspect some improvement opportunities concerning my use of Beautiful Soup, but I'm open to any kind of improvement ideas in general.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from urllib import request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


STANDARD_URL_FORMAT = 'http://{}.stackexchange.com/election/{}?tab=primary'
COM_URL_FORMAT = 'http://{}.com/election/{}?tab=primary'

SITES_INFO_HELPER = [
    (('cr', 'codereview'), STANDARD_URL_FORMAT, 'codereview'),
    (('sf', 'serverfault'), COM_URL_FORMAT, 'serverfault'),
    (('so', 'stackoverflow'), COM_URL_FORMAT, 'stackoverflow'),
]


def build_sites_info():
    sites_info = {}
    for info in SITES_INFO_HELPER:
        names, url_format, url_component = info
        for name in names:
            sites_info[name] = url_format, url_component
    return sites_info


def load_html_doc(url):
    return request.urlopen(url).read()


def get_soup(url):
    html_doc = load_html_doc(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    # print(soup.prettify())  # for debugging
    return soup


def main():
    sites_info = build_sites_info()

    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Show candidates of an SE election in sorted order')
    parser.add_argument('site', choices=sites_info.keys(),
                        help='Site short name or abbreviation')
    parser.add_argument('-n', type=int, default=1,
                        help='Election number')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    site_info = sites_info[args.site]
    url_format, url_component = site_info
    url = url_format.format(url_component, args.n)

    soup = get_soup(url)
    scores = []
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        if tr.find('td', attrs={'class': 'votecell'}):
            username = tr.find(attrs={'class': 'user-details'}).find('a').text
            votes = int(tr.find(attrs={'class': 'vote-count-post'}).text)
            scores.append((username, votes))

    for name, score in sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
        print('{}\t{}'.format(score, name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nice script! But I get this warning when running it: `/home/jacwah/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))`

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't get such warnings, but I see in the docs that the constructor of `BeautifulSoup` needs a second argument, to tell the parser to use. I just tried now `html.parser`, it works well, so I updated the post. I hope your warning will go away too!

Comment: I’d modify the print() statement so that the scores are right-aligned, which will make them look nicer vertically. Also, there’s some [JavaScript on Meta.se](http://jsfiddle.net/hgjzx19x/) which you could probably crib to automate the site list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your list `SITES_INFO_HELPER` remains constant throughout the entire program, that list should be a tuple instead

Tuples are faster than lists and are write-protected, which doesn't make a difference to you because you are writing to them.

Read more about when you should use a tuple and when you should use a list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1708510/3424096).

---

Good job using `ArgumentParser` in your code; that is often something that you don't see used in python code and is actually an extremely useful tool.

---

You could make your code more object oriented by turning the information inside `SITES_INFO_HELPER` into instances of a class, probably called `Site`.

It doesn't have to be anything too complicated; it's just supposed to be a way to store some values:

```
class Site:
    def __init__(self, name, initials, format=STANDARD_URL_FORMAT):
        self.name = name
        self.initials = initials
        self.format = format
```

*Note: I set the `format` property to be `STANDARD_URL_FORMAT` by default because most stack exchange sites follow this format.*

Then, when storing the sites, you'd store them like this:

```
SITES_INFO_HELPER = ( Site("codereview", "cr"), Site("stackoverflow", "so", COM_URL_FORMAT) ...)
```

I'm not entirely sure, but storing site information like this may rid of the need of `build_sites_info`.

---

I think you made a good choice using `urllib` and `BeautifulSoup` together to read the election webpage. And, from what I know about `BeautifulSoup`, what you are doing looks just fine.

Also, looking over the election page layout, how you are scanning the webpage seems to be the only/best way.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using `urllib` for this purpose rather than `requests`?

Comment: @AlexA. Not exactly. However, the use of urllib here is so minimal that a change to requests would be unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, okay. I don't actually know much about the differences between the two modules so I didn't know if there were any advantages to using one over the other. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexA. No problem! I don't know much about them either, but I do know this: requests was created to simplify urllib. I guess if there was more interaction with internet connections, then it'd probably be cleaner to go with requests.